# Visual studio 2017 Info.plist lose Distribution Destination after tab change

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, visual-studio-2017, info.plist

I've a problem when release IOS app with Visual Studio 2017 that i can reproduce doing the following opertions:

1) I need to change the IOS destination version to 9.0 because i must support olders device, so i edit the Info.plist like below:

[image: PICTURE 1]

2)  I publish my ipa file as usual and my destination version of the builded ipa is 11 (i can see it uploading on diawi but even trying to install on a ios8 device that show me the error "Unable to download {app-name} at this time")... mh nice... i go back to Info.plist and i see that the Destination version is blank:

[image: PICTURE 2]

3) I try to edit it again but when i change "tab" or build .ipa file I come back to point 2.

I've just tried the standard things like delete bin/obj and rebuild or disconnect-reconnect the mac but nothing works :(

Some useful things:

1. On IOS 11 the ipa file works perfectly.
2. I'm using an Enterprise realease Certificate.
3. <s>My Mac XCode Version is 9.2 (I've not enought free disk space to upgrade.</s> Updated but no success.
4. I've Already change the data inside the info.plist but seems that it will be ignored:

```html
<key>MinimumOSVersion</key>
 <string>9.0</string>
```

5. I do a clean install on my mac of Hight Sierra + XCode + VS2017 at the last version but nothing has changed :(

Comment: Are you sure that your app does support iOS 8/9 in the first place?

Comment: Yes, i don't think i use functions specified for ios 11 (ios 10 not works too) even if because few days before i can compile for ios 8 without problems without code changes.

Comment: Did you upgrade dependencies which broke the build? Or what did you change? Since when did it stop working?

Comment: I edit some Android code and recopile no dependencies added, i Upgrade Xamarin.Forms to the 3.X.X version from 2.5.X vesion and clean some unused one, but if i downgrade them now i've the same problem...

Comment: Please try to downgrade `Xamarin.Forms` again, delete your `.nuget` folder and caches and every `/bin` and `/obj` folder. Then restart Visual Studio.

Comment: Can you try editing the file (info.plist) and then do 'Save As' on Desktop. Delete the info.plist in your project and copy the version from desktop to your project folder

Comment: Can you also rightclick on the file and see if its locked or readonly

Comment: Nothing of the above works but thanks for the support... the file is not in read only mode. I'm doing a MAC's Restore-To-Fabric process.... After reinstalling all the stuff i hope it works....

Comment: not solved even reinstalling evrything :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was a Visual studio bug.....
Installing the last released VS update fix my problem (Visual studio professional 2017 v15.8.7).
Thanks Evryone for your time :)

Answer (score 1):

Try to edit your info.plist outside of the IDE. I faced a bug in the past that VS2017 overwrote some settings with default values when I used the GUI editor, and because of this I started making all my changes to the plist file manually.

The setting name you need to set manually is probably "MinimumOSVersion" in the file.

```
<key>MinimumOSVersion</key>
<string>9.0</string>
```